# Xcode is terminating when trying to save data to CoreData

Tags: ios, core-data

In my app In the `UIViewController` class I have declared this

```
var subject: Subject?
```

This `Subject` variable gets its value from the previous `ViewController` sometimes and sometimes not but when I try to change it and save it to `CoreData` Xcode **gets terminated** completely without previously showing me any error or crash. Sometimes it **gets terminated** even when I just run the simulator.

In `override func shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier identifier: sender:)` I have this:

```
subject = Subject(context: PersistanceService.context)
    if let dayName = workDay?.dayName {
        subject?.dayName = dayName
    }
    if let textInTextField: String = textFieldSubjectName.text {
        subject?.subjectName = textInTextField
    }
    subject?.startsAt = startsAtOnAddingSubject
```

I did find out that this code makes Xcode terminate but I'm not sure why.The funny thing here is that I get this problem only when running the app on iPhone 7.

**EDIT:**

- **Here I quickly made a screenshot of the console just before Xcode terminated:**

[Part of the console(couldn't capture everything)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihSRf.jpg)

Comment: Can you pinpoint which line causes the issue?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't because as I click the button "save" that I have Xcode terminates right away and I can't see any errors because Xcode is terminated.

Comment: You can also check the screenshot I provided when editing the question. I don't think I'm able to provide any more information about the problem because that is everything I know.Thanks for the help!

Comment: Looks like a migration issue, did you change your schema from the last time you build the app?
Try deleting the app from your device and run it again to check if it works.

Comment: I still don't know what migration issue is but I did what you told me to and it fixed the issue!  Thank you!